# Odds of winning a prize

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the odds of winning a prize in both lottery and keno.

So on the lottery it'd be both for a standard lottery type like a $\frac{6}{49}$ and for a Powerball type with a $\frac{5}{50} + \frac{2}{10}$.

Here is an example of the pay table: Sorry i'm struggling to add a paytable

[paytable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRGcI.png)

Keno it would be on a hit $9$, $12$ and $15$.

I just don't understand the logic behind how to calculate this.

Thanks

Comment: Calculate each probability, and multiply the results.

Comment: If I understand correctly: you want "the odds of winning a prize in a normal lottery" and "the same thing, but in Powerball and Keno", _all separately_. Otherwise I could say you want "odds of winning all three". It's not entirely clear with current wording.

Comment: Sorry - I want to calculate the odds of winning a prize in a normal lottery, that's correct. I'd like to apply the logic of winning a prize calculation to keno and a powerball type lottery. I hope that clears it up. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't clear up anything (or at least not everything). Please assume that we are not familiar with the rules of each game, and specify exact details. The description "So on the lottery it'd be both for a standard lottery type like a $\frac{6}{49}$ and for a Powerball type with a $\frac{5}{50} + \frac{2}{10}$. Keno it would be on a hit $9$, $12$ and $15$.", is insufficient for that matter.

Comment: I'm trying to add a table - Not entirely sure how to do it

Comment: I added a picture of the paytable to the initial question. I hope this helps.

Comment: Paytables aren't needed. All I need is how exactly the Powerball and keno lotteries work, what the jackpot is for Powerball and what you mean by "hitting 9, 12, 15". Describe them as you would to a fellow gambler, and put that in the question.

Comment: Okay so on Keno - for hitting 9, you select 9 numbers between 1-80. The system then draws at random 20 numbers between 1-80 you win based on the wager/bet amount and the paytable applied. 

Lottery - in the image you select 6 from 90 (1-90) balls, and then from a second ball set which is 1 number from 1-90. The draw would pull out 7 balls from 90 and another 1 number is drawn from another set of 90 balls and the result is applied to the paytable above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just concentrate on the probability of hitting the jackpot (lotteries) and hitting all numbers (keno). For a normal lottery (6 from 49, match all for jackpot) it is easy: 1 in $\binom {49}6=13983816$.

For Powerball the jackpot is matching all 6 + 1 chosen numbers. On the ordinary balls, given your initial choice there are only 84 choices for the machine's remaining ball, as compared to $\binom{90}{7}$ possible draws. The "star" ball must match, and the odds of that are 1 in 90. Multiply:
$$\frac{84}{90\binom{90}7}=\frac{7}{56035316700}.$$
For keno, given the initial choice of 9 numbers the machine must select 11 more from 71 numbers. The probability for hitting all is thus
$$\binom{71}{11}/\binom{80}{20}=\frac{17}{23471690}.$$
The same argument works for hitting 12
$$\binom{68}{8}/\binom{80}{20}=\frac{51}{24391353490}$$
and 15.
$$\binom{65}{5}/\binom{80}{20}=\frac{3}{1284030537295}$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but calculating the odds of winning the jackpot is relatively simple. I'm trying to understand how one would calculate the odds of winning ANY prize. I was thinking that potentially it'd be the SUM(All possible combinations)/SUM(All possible winning combinations) but i'm not 100% sure if that'd work.

Comment: For each prize you calculate how many possible machine draws will win it alone for any given bet (e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 6 for lottery), This is doable, but messy - the answer just shows an example. Then you sum all up and divide by how many possible machine draws there are, which gives P(win any prize).